# Why does NHIbernate (Fluent) still execute queries for my Noop properties?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, no-op

I have a **user** object that has a many to many relationship with **project**. In my user mapping, I have this:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Projects).Table("UsersProjects").ParentKeyColumn("UserID").Access.None();
```

When I run a simple get by id query:

```
session.QueryOver<User>()
       .Where(x => x.PrimaryID == id)
       .Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

I get two queries being run - the first is the query to do the get by id, the second is the query to get the list of Projects.

I thought the point of the noop property was so that NHibernate could be aware of a relationship, but not actually populate the property...?
Interestingly, the Projects property is null after the query - so the property isn't being set (making the second query even more redundant!)

I'm using NHibernate v3.1.0.4000 and FluentNHibernate v1.2.0.712

### Edit

I've done a bit of testing and determined that this is not a problem specific to using the fluent query interface. In addition, when I dump out my mappings to hbm files, the mapping for this property is as follows:

```
<set access="none" name="Projects" table="UsersProjects">
  <key>
    <column name="UserID" />
  </key>
  <many-to-many class="Project">
    <column name="ProjectID" />
  </many-to-many>
</set>
```

This looks like what I'd expect (http://ayende.com/blog/4054/nhibernate-query-only-properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Access=none` property refers to the access level of the collection in your POCO; not in your queries. (access can be 'property', 'field', 'public field' etc.). so it has no bearing on how your collection is handled.
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339264/property-access-strategies-in-nhibernate/2339712#2339712) and [here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#Access_strategies)
using `lazy=true` would prevent your collection from being loaded until you reference it (which, as I understand it, is what you want).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - Although I came across the lazy load thing as a way around the problem first, I set your answer as the correct one because of the links :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a hack, but if I add LazyLoad() to the mapping, it prevents the second unwanted query from running:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Projects).Table("UsersProjects").ParentKeyColumn("UserID").LazyLoad().Access.None();
```