# Force NHibernate to get entity that is already in persisted state / 1st level cache

Tags: nhibernate

I have a service object that is responsible for some business logic validation. What it does, before issing Update to repository, is checking whether entity that it works on complies to some business rules.

One of that rules that is must check is if **Status** property of the entity didn't change when compared to entity that is in database. Because I use repositories that share the same **ISession**, when I try to get entity from database, in order to get an object for comparsion:

```
if (fromDbEntity.Status != entity.Status) throw new Exception("Cannot change status...");
```

I'll always get **fromDbEntity** that is in 1st level cache - so I work on the same object.

Is there a way to force NHibernate/Repository to get entity from database even though it's already in the scope of the session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evict `entity` from session before loading `fromDbEntity`

```
session.Evict(entity);
```

You can check the official documentation for more details: [Managing the caches](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-sessioncache)

The con about this is that you will need to manually call `SaveOrUpdate` for `entity` since now the object is out of the session.

Answer (score 3):

You could, as Claudio [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11016582/119230), evict the `entity` from the session, then load your `fromDbEntity`, do the comparison and then [Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate) the entity again with the session.

Other thing you might do is loading the `fromDbEntity` using the [stateless session](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate) instead.

But is this really necessary? Couldn't you just make your `Status` property read-only? NHibernate is perfectly capable of using [fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339264/property-access-strategies-in-nhibernate) for accessing data. Or you could make your property setter `protected`:

```
public virtual Status Status { get; protected set; }
```

This way the user won't be able to change the property value, so there's no need to check whether current value is different from db one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I solved it by clearing the session before any call that I want to go all the way to the data base.

```
session.Clear();
```

It's a little overkill but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The way you sate your logic, it sounds like there's a potential bug.  A much better solution would be to turn on dynamic-update, thus only updating changed values, then validate that no one has changed Status before saving.